# How to convert subprocess.popen.object to normal string in python 2.5?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.5

I am executing below code which is working fine but the ouput it gives is as "subprocess.Popen object at 0x206"

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen 
var1= "I am testing"
Process=Popen('/home/tester/Desktop/test.sh %s' % (str(var1),), shell=True)
print Process
```

returns: `subprocess.Popen object at 0x206`

Also test.sh just echos given variable all it's having is:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo $1 
echo $2
```

Unfortunately I cannot upgrade my application python version from 2.5 hence not able to use the current subprocess features such as check_ouput, I am looking for an solution by which I can convert the given output into normal string?

Comment: Because that's what `Process` is.  If you want to interact with it, it's an object with methods e.g. to return the output of the encapsulated process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass stdout and stderr to Popen and read them:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('/home/tester/Desktop/test.sh %s' % (str(var1),), stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = proc.communicate()  # Read data from stdout and stderr

print out
print err
```

Comment: yup, that's what was missing.